# Requirements for excel data refreshing

Tags: excel, excel-services

What are the requirements to be able to update data that came from Sharepoint (using Export to Excel button) by Excel "Refresh All" button?

On some machines I can refresh (when authentication prompt ask credentials everything works ok) , and in some not (when authentication prompt ask credentials, the credentials are not accepted. Excel prompt appears again and after a new try a error message appears), both with the same user (administrator).

I want to be able to refresh data in all machines and I dont know if I need to Install something in every machine to do this.

Sorry for the Google Translator English.

Answer (score 1):

The repeating credential prompt may be a symptom of a missing trust between client and server. 
I would suggest to add the domain of the SharePoint to the Local Intranet security zone.

1. Run **inetcpl.cpl** in your Windows 10 search or with **Windows Key + R**. This opens the **Internet Options**.
2. Click the security tab and select **Local Intranet**.
3. Then click on **Sites** and **Advanced**.
4. Type in the **URL of your SharePoint** and click **Add**.
5. Click Close and then on **OK** to save this new setting.
6. Close the Internet Explorer and try to open the file.

If this helped you can enroll this setting with group polices on every or specific clients in your network.

Answer (score 0):

This issue cause troubles to me because I am building dashboard from these exported data and need to be refreshed all time during meetings or reporting.

When I "refresh all", it asks credentials and not accepting. I tried to refresh one sheet by another and discovered only on sheet having this issue.

The issue is only that I need to get the right authorities to the original SharePoint Page you exported your data from.

I made long story but to let you understand and apologize for this. hope it can resolve your issue.